# How to change the text color when the user tap on it ? Flutter - Firestore - StreamBuilder

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use Flutter with firestore to collect votes, and I'm struggling with UI.
What I want is when the user tap on the option, something change on the text or the border ...

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Awd.png)
[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnYsH.png)

To add more information, this is my code:

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
return ListTile(
  title: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(210, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.pink[800], // set border color
            width: 3.0), // set border width
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0)), // set rounded corner radius
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.black,
              offset: Offset(0.5, 1))
        ] // make rounded corner of border
        ),
      child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            child: Text(
              document['rep'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
        ),
          ]
      ),
  ),



  onTap: () {
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction(
            (transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
      await transaction.get(document.reference);
      await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
        'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
      });
    });

  },

);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('questions').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading ...');

            return ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 300.0, 50.0, 0.0),
                itemExtent: 100.0,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
              );
          }),


      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Home()));
        },
        child: Text("Home"),
      ),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

int selectedItem = -1; //add in your state

In your list add following :

```
selectedItem == index
            ? Container(color: Colors.white)
            : Container(color: Colors.red));
```

And in

```
onTap: () {
 setState(() {
      selectedItem = selectedIndex;
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, 
can you please explain me ? i did'nt understand where to put the second part , 
selectedItem == index , it gives me an error

Comment: @Space907 child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
        selectedItem = selectedIndex ? Container( color: red
            child: Text(
              document['rep'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
        ) : 
        Container( color : white
            child: Text(
              document['rep'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
        ),

Comment: it doesn't work , selectedIndex still highlighted in list and in onTap.  :/

Comment: Can you please share what changes have you made?

Comment: i did it bellow ... thank you so much for your help  !

Comment: no it didn't, all the name change to red when i click in one answer

Comment: Try 
setState(() {
      selectedItem = 0;
    });
Is it setting only 0th item to Red?

Comment: no, nothing is changed , all still white even if i click on it

Answer (score 0):

```
    int selectedItem = -1;
```

Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {

```
return ListTile(
  title: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(210, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.pink[800], // set border color
            width: 3.0), // set border width
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0)), // set rounded corner radius
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.black,
              offset: Offset(0.5, 1))
        ] // make rounded corner of border
        ),
      child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            selectedItem = selectedIndex ?
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              document['rep'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
        ) :
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
                document['rep'],
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
          ]
      ),
  ),

  onTap: () {
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction(
            (transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
      await transaction.get(document.reference);
      await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
        'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
      });
    });

    setState(() {
      selectedItem = selectedIndex;
    });


  },

);
```

}